# Infinite container loads the information and dialog gets stuck

Tags: codenameone

I'm using the infinite container and it will load the information and stuck with dialog sometimes. I would like to know how can i dispose it. I'm already using dispose() method. If I do Pull to refresh this dialog will go away. I would like to know I can so something about it on IOS

```
 public Component[] fetchComponents(int index, int amount) {
            boolean overrideCacheFlg = true;
            if (index == 0) {
                counterDate = currentDate;
            }
            SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
            final int DAY = 24 * 60 * 60000;
            Date dd = endDate;
            if (endDate == null) {
                dd = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + DAY * Server.instance.getAppointmentDaysPerBatch());
            }
            boolean flg = Server.instance.isOffline();
            Appointment[] apps = Server.instance.fetchAppointments(counterDate, dd, folder, false);
            if (apps == null) {
                apps = Server.instance.fetchAppointments(counterDate, dd, folder, false);
            }
            if (apps == null) {
                apps = Server.instance.fetchAppointments(counterDate, dd, folder, true);
                overrideCacheFlg = false;
            }
            ArrayList<Component> response = new ArrayList<>();
            String lastDate = sd.format(counterDate);
            response.add(new Label(lastDate, "Header"));
            if (apps == null) {
                Component[] aa = null;
                SpanLabel loadAppts = new SpanLabel("Load the Appointments Again");
                FontImage.setMaterialIcon(loadAppts, FontImage.MATERIAL_CACHED, 8.0f);
//                Container ck = new Container();
//                ck.add(BorderLayout.center(loadAppts));
                loadAppts.setUIID("LoadAppointments");
                if (index <= 0) {
                    aa = new Component[]{BorderLayout.center(loadAppts)};
                }
                return aa;
            } **else if (apps.length == 0) {**
                Component[] aa = null;
                if (index <= 0) {
                    aa = new Component[]{new Label("No Appointments", "Header")};
                }
                return aa;
            }
```

Comment: That's an infinite progress, not a dialog. It happens if fetch components doesn't return null

Comment: @shai. it doesn't happen all the time. It happens sporadically. I would like to know how to avoid this. Please advise.

Comment: Its a bug in your implementation of fetch components that returns an empty array instead of null for some cases.

Comment: @Shai, I have added the code here. I see the infinite progress get stuck when list size is zero. Please look at the condition where ** is there. First time when loop is iterated index = -1 and second time index becomes 1 and returns null. I still loading image after "No Appointments" label. Ifuse pull to refreshon the container that  loading image never gets stuck. This is happening more on ios and when connects to Wifi. IT is not happening when connected to 4G as the time takes for loading is more. Please advise.

Comment: Please advise on the change and how the index is working here. Thx

Comment: You need to add special logic that returns null at some point after returning the "No Appointments" label. Until you return null the infinite container thinks there is still more data to fetch

Comment: @Shai..I'm returning null. Please see the loop here...

Comment: else if (apps.length == 0) {
                Component[] aa = null;
                if (index <= 0) {
                    aa = new Component[]{new Label("No Appointments", "Header")};
                }
                return aa;

Comment: It returns null at the end. Infinite loading attached image is not active. I mean loading finished and loading image is stuck in the disabled mode  below "No Appointments" header.did that make sense. Please advise.

Comment: I don't see that logic in the code, I suggest placing a breakpoint there and debugging the calls to this. It should invoke that method repeatedly.